# I get a black screen with a tab bar outline containing no items

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I get a black screen with a tab bar outline containing no items. This occurs after I login using firebase. the login page works perfectly however for some reason the tab navigation screwed up the app which was working perfectly.

I tried removing the pictures I'm using as background images for the tab bar items.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you're able, please share the code that sets up the tab bar.

Comment: i didn't use code, I selected the viewcontrollerd I wanted and embedded them in a tab contoller

Comment: Seems like your tab bar doesn't have any view controllers, check your storyboard.

Comment: Either way, I think you'll need to provide more information about what you expect to see, how you're using Firebase and how you're setting up your UI, with a Storyboard or otherwise.

Comment: go through this link https://codewithchris.com/ios-tab-bar-app/ and try to understand.

Comment: I solved the problem, i was embedding the tab view in a navigation controller instead of embedding the navigation controller inside the tab controller. Thanks for your help anyways guys!